# Django collecstatic with crontab

Tags: django, cron

I have Django website with **scraper** which every day download images, so I want to automate collectstatic with crontab
I  tried this  add to crontab.cr

```
yes | python2.7 manage.py collectstatic
```

but I get error :

You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings:

/home/mojbutik/webapps/webshop/myproject/static

This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?

CommandError: Collecting static files cancelled.

Can someone tell me how to do it...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did you try that command?

> python manage.py collectstatic --noinput