# What does the '--noinput' option do when collecting static files using django?

Tags: django, collectstatic

So I was having issues collecting my static files using the 'python manage.py collectstatic' command. it returned "CommandError: Collecting static files cancelled." I was searching and found the solution reading this post [Django collecstatic with crontab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27323350/django-collecstatic-with-crontab)

It's now working and successfully collected my new static files. 
Could someone enlighten me on what the '--noinput' option is actually doing?

Answer (score 3):

For all the numb people like me. You have to write 'yes' instead of 'y'. Therefore for some the '--noinput' option works perfectly well :-O

Answer (score 2):

When you run manage.py collectstatic, you will need to press "Y or N" to create the required folders like "admin", if you run manage.py collecstatic --noinput, django will run without prompt.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#cmdoption-collectstatic-noinput

Comment: Clicking "Y" still returns the error "CommandError: Collecting static files cancelled". Clicking "N" also returns the same error "CommandError: Collecting static files cancelled". Adding the --noinput option returns "0 static files copied to '/home/someone/someone.pythonanywhere.com/static', 121 unmodified." 0 static files because I have no new changes since the error..... hmmm